# How to assign Multiple GridView for multiple UI filter selection in asp.net WF with c#

Tags: asp.net, gridview, html-select

I have four `DropDownList` controls. **Year, Country, PC, CC**

Selecting a **Year** populates the **Country** along with **PC** and **CC** `DropDownList`. However, if I only select **Country** and hit the **Submit** `Button`then the result should be displayed in a `GridView` as follows:

> List of PC || Total Transaction Amount
>
> PC1........................ 500.00
>   PC2........................ 600.00

But if I select a **Country**, **PC** and **CC** then the results are different which also need to be displayed in a `GridView`:

> Accounts || Total Transaction Amount
>
> ACC1........................ 100.00
>   ACC2........................ 200.00

Similarity between these two process is that I will have to use the last `GridView` when I click on one of the **List of PC** from the first `GridView`.

**Question** :

1. Would I have have to use separate `GridView` controls for these two different use cases and bind search results to different `GridView`?
2. I have 2 methods where one returns a **Total** for a PC for a selected **Country** and the other method returns a **Total** for an **Account** for selected **Country**, **PC** and **CC**, in this case can I literally do the following where I am using same GridView for different results, which is not actually working?

   ```
       protected void _UIButtonSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       IEnumerable<AccountTransactionViewModel> transactions = null;
       IEnumerable<TransactionTotalForProfitcenterViewModel> totalProfitcenterTranAmount = null;

       if ((_UIFilterDDCountry.SelectedValue) != null)
       {
           //transactions = ts.GetAllTransactionsByCountry(_UIFilterDDCountry.SelectedItem.Value);
           totalProfitcenterTranAmount = ts.GetTotalTransactionsForProfitcenter(_UIFilterDDCountry.SelectedItem.Value);

           _UITransactionGridView.DataSource = totalProfitcenterTranAmount;
       }

       else if ((_UIFilterDDCountry.SelectedValue) != null 
               && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_UIFilterDDProfitcenter.SelectedValue) 
           && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_UIFilterDDCostcenter.SelectedValue))
       {
           transactions = ts.GetAllTransactionsByYearCountryProfitcenterCostcenter(
                                           _UIFilterDDCountry.SelectedItem.Value,
                                           int.Parse(_UIFilterDDProfitcenter.SelectedItem.Value),
                                           int.Parse(_UIFilterDDCostcenter.SelectedItem.Value));
           _UITransactionGridView.DataSource = transactions;
       }
       _UITransactionGridView.DataBind();
       _UITransactionGridView.PageIndex = 0;
   }
   ```

Would really appreciate if anyone can just guide me (new to asp.net and c#) through to a correct direction and suggest perhaps better option, logic, idea etc.

Comment: _UIFilterDDCountry.SelectedValue can it be null? Also what are the values being bound to the dropdown.

Comment: Also you need to set the country dropdown to be mandatory, remove the country dropdown value check in your method, and reverse the condition check without country dropdown check

Comment: No _UIFilterDDCountry.SelectedValue can not be null.The values are string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIFilterDDCountry.SelectedValue can it be null? Also what are the values being bound to the dropdown.

Also you need to set the country dropdown to be mandatory, remove the country dropdown value check in your method, and reverse the condition check without country dropdown check

Try using the dropdown selectedindex value rather than selected value.

You can go ahead using a single gridview, but that would have some code to be written to change the column names and so on during runtime(code behind) based on the options selected. Else simply use 2 gridview controls and set its visiblity based on the option selected.

Comment: using SelectedIndex for the DropDownList worked along with swapping the if statement clause. For the time being I am using two different GridView controls. Thanks for the suggestions.